# getting the last AUTO INCREMENT - how do I specify the table for my query with mysqli_insert_id?

Tags: php, sql

`mysqli_insert_id` takes one parameter, the connection to the database.

But I have two INSERTs in my PHP code, both using the same connection which is defined in my `dbConnect.php`. How can I distinguish between the two ?

I am looking for the AUTO INCREMENT value in this query :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO category VALUES(NULL,'{$category}', '$user_id')";
```

If I put this code as the *second* query below, then it works, probably because `mysqli_insert_id` is taking the latest value in the code, but I'd prefer to be able to specify the value I'm looking for, rather than doing it in this haphazard sort of way.

So, how do I specify the table for my query with mysqli_insert_id?

```
<?php require('dbConnect.php'); 

session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

// Create new record in the db, if the 'Add New Record' button is clicked

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

    $category = ($_POST['category']);
    $name = ($_POST['name']);
    $phonenumber = ($_POST['phonenumber']);
    $address = ($_POST['address']);
    $comment = ($_POST['comment']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO category VALUES(NULL,'{$category}', '$user_id')";

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO review VALUES(NULL,'$user_id', '$user_id', '{$name}','{$phonenumber}','{$address}', '{$comment}')";

    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        if ($con->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    echo mysqli_insert_id($con);
    }} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
}


$con->close();


?>
```

Comment: From the documentation: "*Returns the auto generated id used in the **last** query*". This means that if you want the ID generated by the first query, you'll have to call `mysqli_insert_id()` between the two queries. To get the second one, use it again after the second query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PHP main documentation on [mysqli_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

> Return Values:
>
> The value of the AUTO_INCREMENT field that was updated by the previous query. Returns zero if there was no previous query on the connection or if the query did not update an AUTO_INCREMENT value.

Basically in order to get both id's, you have to ask for the auto_increment from the database twice.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO category VALUES(NULL,'{$category}', '$user_id')";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO review VALUES(NULL,'$user_id', '$user_id', '{$name}','{$phonenumber}','{$address}', '{$comment}')";
$id1 = 0;
$id2 = 0;
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $id1 = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    if ($con->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        $id2 = mysqli_insert_id($con);
        echo "New record created successfully";
        echo "ID1 is $id1 and ID2 is $id2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok, need to call it twice, thanks. By the way, small but important typo in there : `$id2 = mysql_insert_id($con);` should be `$id2 = mysqli_insert_id($con);`

Answer (score 1):

Since the function returns only the id form the latest query, you could try something like this:

```
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    if ($con->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
        echo $id;
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $first_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    if ($con->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        $second_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
        echo "New record created successfully";
        echo "First: " . $first_id . " Second: " . $second_id;
    }
}
```